# Unable to grant myself access to tables that I created in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle DB and I am using the system username. Using C# I created a few tables using the system username/password. When I log into sql developer and view the privileges on that table, it does not show the system user (which has a dba role and a MGMT_USER role) as having select/insert/update/delete permissions (or any permissions for that matter).

"You may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself"

Why does my admin user not have access to these tables and how do I get it?

Comment: **Never**, ever use the SYSTEM (or the SYS) account to create regular tables. Create a regular user and use that. Do **NOT** use the SYSTEM account for anything else than DBA work (e.g. creating users)

Answer (score 4):

What @TenG said - you can't grant privs on objects you own to yourself - you have those privs inherently as the OWNER.

More importantly, DO NOT use the SYSTEM account to create objects, especially don't create them IN the SYSTEM schema.

Use SYSTEM to create your application user, log in as THAT user, and THEN create your objects.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle,  being the owner of the means you have implicit grants on the tables.

No need to grant privs to yourself on your own objects.